# Fail2Ban fails to start on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, firewalld, fail2ban

I'm running CentOS 7, all fully updated, and am trying to get Fail2Ban to work, but I'm running into problems.

Specifically, I'm trying to block brute force SSH attacks. I'm pretty sure I've set up everything right – enabled the sshd jail in `jail.local`, using `firewallcmd-ipset` as the ban action, definitely using Firewalld, not using SELinux.

But when I start Fail2Ban, here's what's in `/var/log/fail2ban.log`:

```
2017-06-21 06:11:44,186 fail2ban.server         [3357]: INFO    Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.9.6
2017-06-21 06:11:44,186 fail2ban.database       [3357]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
2017-06-21 06:11:44,188 fail2ban.jail           [3357]: INFO    Creating new jail 'sshd'
2017-06-21 06:11:44,206 fail2ban.jail           [3357]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' uses systemd {}
2017-06-21 06:11:44,230 fail2ban.jail           [3357]: INFO    Initiated 'systemd' backend
2017-06-21 06:11:44,232 fail2ban.filter         [3357]: INFO    Set maxRetry = 3
2017-06-21 06:11:44,232 fail2ban.filter         [3357]: INFO    Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
2017-06-21 06:11:44,233 fail2ban.actions        [3357]: INFO    Set banTime = 86400
2017-06-21 06:11:44,233 fail2ban.filter         [3357]: INFO    Set findtime = 3600
2017-06-21 06:11:44,234 fail2ban.filter         [3357]: INFO    Set maxlines = 10
2017-06-21 06:11:44,320 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [3357]: INFO    Added journal match for: '_SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service + _COMM=sshd'
2017-06-21 06:11:44,335 fail2ban.jail           [3357]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
2017-06-21 06:11:44,864 fail2ban.action         [3357]: ERROR   ipset create fail2ban-sshd hash:ip timeout 86400
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p all -m multiport --dports 44 -m set --match-set fail2ban-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable -- stdout: ''
2017-06-21 06:11:44,865 fail2ban.action         [3357]: ERROR   ipset create fail2ban-sshd hash:ip timeout 86400
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p all -m multiport --dports 44 -m set --match-set fail2ban-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable -- stderr: '\x1b[91mError: COMMAND_FAILED\x1b[00m\n'
2017-06-21 06:11:44,865 fail2ban.action         [3357]: ERROR   ipset create fail2ban-sshd hash:ip timeout 86400
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p all -m multiport --dports 44 -m set --match-set fail2ban-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable -- returned 13
2017-06-21 06:11:44,865 fail2ban.actions        [3357]: ERROR   Failed to start jail 'sshd' action 'firewallcmd-ipset': Error starting action
```

As you'll note, everything runs smoothly until `firewall-cmd` is tried. The commands it's trying to run are:

`ipset create fail2ban-sshd hash:ip timeout 86400`

followed by

`firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p all -m multiport --dports 44 -m set --match-set fail2ban-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable`

If I try to run those myself, the `ipset` command works fine, but the `firewall-cmd` one returns with `Error: COMMAND_FAILED`. So, I'm guessing it's a problem with the command that Fail2Ban is trying to send to `firewall-cmd` – but I don't know enough about Firewalld to fix it.

(Oh, SSH is on port 44 because I've found that it massively reduces drive-by attacks, so let's not get into the pros and cons of that!

Also, `systemctl status fail2ban` shows everything to be running smoothly, no problems reported there. I only noticed this when I logged in and saw that there'd been a bunch of failed login attempts, which is rare what with the port change and all.

Finally, `uname -r` returns `3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.centos.plus.x86_64` so I'm fairly sure it's not the OpenVZ problem which I've seen as a cause of this elsewhere.)

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?  If so, temporarily disable it with `# setenforce 0`.  If that works, you know it's an SELinux issue and can investigate that path.  To enable it again, use `# setenforce 1`.

Comment: @garethTheRed No I'm not using SELinux, so it must be something else…

Comment: Does your version of `firewalld` have support for `ipset`? See https://firewalld.org/2015/12/ipset-support also for correct use examples.

Comment: Did you ever resolve the problem? What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

From faqforge.com: https://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-use-iptables-on-centos-7/

> Centos 7 replaced the traditional IPTables Linux Kernel Firewall with
>   the Firewalld service. There are still a lot of scripts available that
>   require the use of IPTables. A common example is the software
>   Fail2ban.

So try stopping firewalld (`systemctl stop firewalld`) and install iptables (`yum install iptables-services`) and `systemctl start iptables`.

Then, set like this the banaction in the `jail.local`:

```
banaction = iptables-multiport
banaction_allports = iptables-allports
```

and then restart.

Comment: I don't have iptables installed, CentOS 7 comes with firewalld, which is up and running normally.